# How should client send json data to PHP

Tags: java, php, json

I have used php for server side and my client(A java program) sends a post request with json data as parameter. I am able to receive the data but the jsonData is no decoding. I am sending a valid JSON.
Below is my Client program.

```
public class ExampleHttpPost
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
  {
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/hello.php");
    List<BasicNameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    try {
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", (new JSONObject("{\"imei\":\"imei1\"}")).toString()));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    // Get the HTTP Status Code
    int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    // Get the contents of the response
    InputStream input = resEntity.getContent();
    String responseBody = IOUtils.toString(input);
    input.close();

    // Print the response code and message body
    System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: "+statusCode);
    System.out.println(responseBody);
  }
}
```

And my hello.php

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['data'];
var_dump($data);
$obj = json_decode($data);
if($obj==NULL){
    echo "Decoding error";
}
echo $obj['imei'];
?>
```

Output :

```
HTTP Status Code: 200
string(20) "{\"imei\":\"imei1\"}"
Decoding error
```

Comment: `obj->imei` or `json_decode($data, true)`

Comment: disable magic quotes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your Java Application is adding slashes to the string or as suggested in the comments the PHP app is probably adding slashes to the quotes to avoid SQL injection
Try if you can get it to work by adding

```
$data = stripslashes($data);
```

Above the json_decode part

Comment: or the PHP application has some deprecated function enabled to add slashes on each quote

Comment: True, to avoid SQL injection and such.

Comment: Yep, but you know that magic quotes gpc is the wrongest way to prevent it :-)

Comment: I wouldn't go that way, but I just assume that's why it's happening.